# Creating a text file for each phrase in string in Python

Tags: python, list, text

I have the following list in Python

> ["trovare", "mostrare", "convincere", "spiegare", "vedere"]

Is there a way to create a group of empty txt files in a specific folder on my desktop that would look like this:

> trovare.txt,
>   mostrare.txt,
>   convincere.txt,
>   spiegare.txt,
>   vedere.txt

Answer (score 2):

[`Path.touch()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.touch) can be used to create empty files.

Try this:

```
from pathlib import Path

filenames = ["trovare", "mostrare", "convincere", "spiegare", "vedere"]
folder_path = '~/desktop/'

for filename in filenames:
    Path(folder_path + filename + '.txt').touch()
```

Replace the `folder_path` with the path to the folder that should contain the files

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is possible.

```py
import os

path = '/your_folder_path'
filenames = ["trovare", "mostrare", "convincere", "spiegare", "vedere"]

for filename in filenames:
    with open(os.path.join(path, filename+'.txt'), 'w')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for fn in ["trovare", "mostrare", "convincere", "spiegare", "vedere"]:
    open(fn + '.txt', 'w').close()
```